# Как получить объект из List по условию, при этом удалив его из списка?

Tags: java, list, foreach

Есть класс `Alpha`, у него `String name QWERTY`
Есть `Arraylist list`
Экземпляр туда добавлен, но вернуть его не могу.

```
Alpha ah1 = removeAndGet("QWERTY");

Alpha removeAndGet(String name) {
     Alpha temp = null;
     for(Alpha element: list) {
          if(element.getName().equals(name)) {
               temp = list.get(list.indexOf(element));
               list.remove(list.indexOf(element));
          }   
     }
     return temp;
}
```

Получаю:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Ни стрим , ничего не помогает. `list.removeIf(o->o.equals(alpha));` это на удаление отдельно работает `list.remove(list.indexOf(alpha));` и это тоже а по условию невозможно.

Comment: этот цикл for доступен только на чтение, либо используйте цикл через `i=0` либо цикл по итератору.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Через Stream

Изменять список внутри for-each нельзя. Можно отделить поиск от удаления через Stream API:

```
static Alpha removeAndGet(String name) {
    //получаем первый подходящий объект
    //или null, если таких нет
    Alpha temp = list.stream()
        .filter(a -> name.equals(a.getName()))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
    //удаляем *ВСЕ* объекты с таким именем
    list.removeIf(a -> name.equals(a.getName()));
    return temp;
}
```

Как [@Andrew Bystrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177093/andrew-bystrov) пишет в комментах, здесь будет два прохода: первый — для поиска до найденного элемента, второй — для удаления по всему списку. С помощью `Optional.isPresent` можно попробовать избежать второго прохода если элемент не был найден.

Исполняемый пример (https://ideone.com/B1qski):

```
import java.util.*;
class Ideone {
    static List<Alpha> list;
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String name = "qwerty";
        list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Alpha("foo"), new Alpha(name), 
                                             new Alpha("bar"), new Alpha("lol")));

        Alpha temp = removeAndGet(name);

        System.out.println(temp); //qwerty
        System.out.println(list); //[foo, bar, lol]
    }
    static Alpha removeAndGet(String name) {
        //получаем первый подходящий объект
        //или null, если таких нет
        Alpha temp = list.stream()
                         .filter(a -> name.equals(a.getName()))
                         .findFirst()
                         .orElse(null);
        //удаляем *ВСЕ* объекты с таким именем
        list.removeIf(a -> name.equals(a.getName()));
        return temp;
    }
    static class Alpha {
        String name;
        Alpha(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

### Через Iterator

Можно написать без Stream API, по-старому, через [`Iterator.remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--):

```
Alpha removeAndGet(String name) {
    Alpha result = null;
    Iterator<Alpha> iterator = list.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        Alpha a = iterator.next();
        if(name.equals(a.getName())) {
            //так будет присвоен последний найденный элемент
            //если важно выбрать первый, то нужно добавить проверку на null
            result = a; 
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Пример: https://ideone.com/qnGQux

Comment: Небольшой комент - во 1-ых, через стрим плохо, т.к. будет 2 прохода, а во 2-ых, через стрим красивее будет сделать `.ifPresent(a -> list.removeIf(...))` вместо `.orElse(null)`

Comment: @AndrewBystrov Спасибо, включил комментарий в ответ. В один проход через стрим я не придумал. Стримы в любом случае не очень быстры, т.ч. я написал наиболее ясный, а не быстрый, код. Вообще, оптимизацию кода я доверяю автору вопроса, скорее всего, если важна производительность, то лучше использовать вариант с `Iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

Надо использовать перебирание через i, foreach не предназначен для изменения списка:

```
Alpha removeAndGet(String name){
     Alpha temp = null;
     for(int i = 0; i < list.size();) {
         Alpha tmp = list.remove(i);
         if(tmp.getName().equals(name)) temp = tmp;
     }
     return temp;
 }
```

Comment: получается цикл по итератору работает только на чтение? remove из него сделать нельзя?
и тогда стрим тоже на чтение работает и стрим листа типа list.stream(). и т.д remove из листа сета мапы сделать нельзя?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: про стрим плиз еще прокоментируйте

Comment: Если сравнивать конкретно имя, то надо писать так: list.removeIf(alpha -> alpha.name.equals(name));

Comment: чтобы не делать два прохода - можно ли стримом достать и удалить? за один проход?
Alpha al2 = Pool.list.stream().findFirst().filter(alpha -> alpha.getName().equals("QWERTY")).get();
        Pool.list.removeIf(alpha -> alpha.getName().equals("QWERTY"));

Comment: Кстати, допустил ошибку, в моём коде не надо писать i++ из-за того, что список укорачивается. Исправил.

Comment: @Stanislav можно написать list.removeIf(alpha -> !alpha.getName().equals("QWERTY"));, а затем return list.get(0);
при использовании стрима надо сначала отфильтровать, а потом вызывать метод findFirst().

Comment: @Stanislav можете поставить галочку под моим ответом?